# Wrap img after getting to a certain width by using only css and html?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex-container with a structure like this:

- Flex-container

  - flex-container 1

    - h1
    - p
    - button
  - flex-container 2

    - image

[image: Preview]

I want this image to wrap when it goes below a certain size (let's say 250px).

On shrinking the browser size i wanted to get both `content-left` and `content-right` in one column instead of single row.

I thought setting `min-width` will help achieving this but after setting min-width to some value, image stops shrinking and stays in right. How can achieve this.

This is my HTML and CSS:

```css
img {
  margin: auto 5%;
  width: 90%;
  min-width: 250px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 100px 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.content-left {
  display: flex;
  width: 40%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.content-right {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-left">
    <h1 id="content-head">This website is awesome</h1>
    <p id="content-data" class="header-item">
      This website has some subtext that goes here under the main title. It's smaller font and color is lower contrast
    </p>
    <button type="button" id="content-button">Sign-up</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content-right">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" alt="motion-blurred image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please find an image on placeholder.com or similar to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adding `min-width: 250px;` to `.content-left` looks to be enough. I guess in that case, content-left and content-right should get full width. Added a new rule to the css with a media query to achieve that.

```css
img {
  margin: auto 5%;
  width: 90%;
  min-width: 250px;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 100px 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.content-left {
  display: flex;
  width: 40%;
  min-width: 250px;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

.content-right {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .content-left {
    width: unset;
  }
  .content-right {
    width: unset;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-left">
    <h1 id="content-head">This website is awesome</h1>
    <p id="content-data" class="header-item">
      This website has some subtext that goes here under the main title. It's smaller font and color is lower contrast
    </p>
    <button type="button" id="content-button">Sign-up</button>
  </div>
  <div class="content-right">
    <img src="./image" alt="motion-blurred image" />
  </div>
</div>
```